# Time complexity when recurrence relation tree method results in unbalanced tree?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

**Problem:** Consider the following variant of Mergesort. If the array has more than two elements, it recursively sorts the first two-third and the last one-third. Then, it merges the first two-third with the last one-third. If the array has at most two elements, then it trivially sorts the array. For completeness, here is the pseudocode for sorting the array `A[l..r]`.

[image]

Write a recurrence relation for the worst-case running time of Newsort. Solve the recurrence relation to obtain a Θ-bound on the running time of the algorithm, in terms of the length of the array. You must use the tree method to solve the recurrence. You may also ignore floors and ceilings in your calculations.

---

**My attempt:**

[image]

As you can see, the complexity of the algorithm must be somewhere in between the complexity of its longest and shortest branches:

- Shortest branch (the last "fully balanced" level): cn*log_{3}(n)
- Longest branch: cn*log_{3/2}(n)

**How do I find the true time complexity?**

Answer (score 0):

If you know the runtime is going to be between `cn * log_{3} (n)` and `c n * log_{3/2}(n)`, then the runtime is `Theta(n log(n))`.

This follows from the change-of-base formula, which states `log_{3/2}(n) = \log_{3} (n) / log_{3} (3/2)`, and the definition of big-Theta.

Edit: OP does not believe in change-of-base formula, so I will prove it quickly.

Consider positive numbers `a, b, c` with `a, b != 1`. I claim that `log_{a}(c) = log_{b}(c) / log_{b}(a)`. It suffices to show that `log_{a}(c) log_{b}(a) = log_{b}(c)`.

Indeed, it suffices to show that `b ^ (log_{a}(c) log_{b}(a)) = c`. We see that `b ^ (log_{a}(c) log_{b}(a)) = (b^(log_{b}(a))) ^ (log_{a}(c)) = a^ (log_{a}(c)) = c`, as required.

Comment: Im not sure that last equation of yours is correct

Comment: Sorry, I meant I dont understand how you use the change of base formula to show that the running time is n*log_{2}(n). Why isnt the complexity simply Theta(n*log_{3}(n))?

Comment: @Nova It is Theta(n log_{3}(n)), which is also Theta(n log(n)).

Comment: Doesnt Theta(n log(n)) grow faster than Theta(n log_{3}(n))? Which one is the tighter bound?

Comment: @Nova Note that by change of base, Theta(n log_{a}(n)) = Theta(n log_{b}(n)) for all a, b > 1. So they are the same bound no matter what base you pick when you say Theta(n log(n)).